Save a Python object and load it without any context
I am trying to save the instance of a Python object to a file.
My problem is that when I use pickle.dump() and then pickle.load() it works if and only if I am in the same file. If I do pickle.dump("dump.pkl") in 'file A' and pickle.load("dump.pkl") in 'file B', I get get following error:
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'person' on <module '__main__'>
Would there be a way to make this work? What I want is to be able to dump my object in a file and then, If I send this file to someone else who only knows about this file (not about the class of the instance I dumped), he can reconstruct the instance on his side.
EDIT: Here is my code
class PersonWrapper:
    def __init__(self, person):
        self.person = person

    def save_person(self, save_path):
        with open(save_path, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(self, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    @staticmethod
    def load_person(path):
        try:
            with open(path, "rb") as f:
                loaded_data = pickle.load(f)

            person = getattr(loaded_data, "person", None)

            if person is None:
                raise ValueError("One required attribute is missing.")

            new_instance = PersonWrapper(person=person)

            return new_instance

In 'file A':
person = Person()

PersonWrapper(person).save_person(
    "dump.pkl"
)

In 'file B' (where the error is thrown):
personWrapper = PersonWrapper().load_person(
    "dump.pkl"
)

Thanks

Please add minimal reproducible example.

The signature of the function is pickle.dump(obj, file, ..., so the code you showed (where only the filename is passed as a parameter) is not complete, so it is harder to diagnose; please add a functioning example

Sorry for that, edit is added.

Why the trouble of the wrapper class.?  just have functions to do the save/restore of a person.

I have tried but I get the same error... The problem is that I can restore If I am in the same file as the one where I dumped but if I send the dump to a friend, he cannot load the dump

Place the PersonWrapper class (and other classes pickle may need) in a separate module and import it from there. The initial Python script has only the internal name __main__ and can't be found by pickle if another script is used to start the program.

Note that you are trying to save picklewrapper in the save but you think you are restoring the person in the restore.  you might want to save self.person instead of self.

@LhasaDad If you think about it, Person is also a wrapper from different attributes so if I cannot save the state of this instance, It will not work for a Person instance. I want to save the attributes of the instance.

@Bonsaï  If You think about it the reconstructed pickled value will be a Person Wrapper with a Person attribute, etc.  You are then passing that to PersonWrapper as the thing to wrap.   You do need to either not do that and returned the reconstructed object directly or save only the person info.  either of those will get you the right result on restore.   I would still follow Michael's advice to mvoe the class file away from your main or better yet. skip the wrapper and just have functions to save/restore the object in a utility module.

@MichaelButscher Thanks for your comment. I have deployed PersonWrapper to pypi. How do I put in practice what you told me? At the moment I do from deployedpackage import PersonWrapper and then I use PersonWrapper.save_person(...) to create a dump. I send it to my friend and he does PersonWrapper.load_person(...) (of course he has the pip lib installed). He gets the error. I don't want to send him the Person class. Is it still possible to make this work?

Pickle needs the Person class as well (and in the same module where it was on pickling) when unpickling an instance of it. The class itself isn't stored in the PKL file.
